# Can the MATLAB Runtime execute on AWS Lambda?

Tags: matlab, amazon-web-services, lambda, matlab-compiler

I have a project API that requires some MATLAB code to run.

Currently, the MATLAB code is compiled using the MATLAB Compiler and runs with the MATLAB Runtime and Python on EC2.

I'm trying to migrate away from EC2 into AWS Lambda. This requires me to package the MATLAB compiled executable into the Lambda package somehow.

As I see it, there are two options:

1. Somehow get the MATLAB Compiler to compile a *purely* static executable
2. Package and use the MATLAB Runtime with my Lamda function (The runtime currently sits somewhere at ~1GB of space, so this doesn't seem feasable)

Has anyone had any experience using MATLAB on AWS Lambda or something similar? Do I have any alternatives from here?

Comment: Did you have any success?

Comment: @Matt Unfortunately not. We had to go with EC2 to support the runtime.

Comment: @Gbps Can you tell me where you faced the issue with this use case?

Comment: @Gbps ok - I have it running. If you want to do this, track me down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have experience running an AWS lambda function in this way but you shouldn't really have a problem.

There are AWS docs on how to do this. Perhaps start here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/running-executables-in-aws-lambda/

I have done this in the past with a Node.js executable of version that was not available in the standard Lambda stack at the time.

The basic steps are:

1. Set up an EC2 instance running Amazon Linux
2. Compile your binary on that instance.
3. Configure your bundle (you will need to see more docs on how to do this)
4. Zip your bundle
5. Upload to your Lambda function (either cli or through console)

There's no reason you shouldn't be able to get this done with a matlab executable, barring the total size of the bundle. If the bundle size is too large, you may run into restrictions and cold-start issues.

Hope this helps.

Comment: EC2 is not AWS Lambda

Comment: @Matt The explanation probably wasn't very clear. The EC2 is used for bundling. So you can build from source, create a package which CAN run on a lambda... and use that as the basis of your lambda instance. I think since writing that question, AWS has also released more tooling to support using alternative binaries and libraries.